# Why is my advertisement of a proposal being downvoted?

Tags: discussion

https://biology.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3145/1809

I wish to understand the reasons.  What makes you reach the downvoted button and what can I do better?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This proposal seems to be entirely unrelated to Biology. Advertising proposals on other SE sites can be very effective, but only if there is a significant overlap between the communities.

You're advertising a proposal that has no connection to Biology, so I'm not surprised it isn't received well.

Comment: Okay. But, well, I thought the people interested in biology can be interested in arts too. Probably I was wrong. Thanks for the explanation.